# Allowing click-through with two hit testable controls

Tags: wpf

I have two controls stacked on top of each other as such:

[image]

Button1 is ZIndex 2, Button2 is ZIndex 1.

Both need to be hit testable, as I need to listen to Button1's MouseEnter event for other system functions. But I also need to be able to have Button2 be clickable. I'm not quite sure how I can get this functionality to pan out (since I can't just set the Button1 to IsHitTestableFalse). Is there some sort of way I can say, in Button1's Click event

```
if (hasElementBeneath):
   click that element instead
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly the trick is rather to prevent the "click" from the inner button to be handled by the outer button too.

To accomplish this: In the click handler for the inner button set the `Handled` property of the supplied `RoutedEventArgs` to `true`.

Like this:

```
    <Button Click="Button1_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>Button 1</TextBlock>
            <Button Click="Button2_Click" Margin="10">Button 2</Button>
        </StackPanel>            
    </Button>
```

and:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button1 clicked!");
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button2 clicked!");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```